# Apply styles all <span> except elements inside <pre> or <code>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

As I have difficulty reading some websites with a small and peculiar typeface, I'm writing snippets to override stylesheet of website itself. Like below

```
body, p, a, span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "readable sans-serif font" !important;
}
```

but it applies to `<span>` inside `<pre>` or `<code>` then the `monospace` font turns to the sans-serif font.
It often occurs with a source code with syntax highlight.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combined selectors to reset the font-family to the (inherited) font of the `<pre>` or `<code>` parent element, like this:

```css
body, p, a, span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
pre span,
code span {
  font-family: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<span>This is a span</span>
<pre>This is a pre tag. <span>And this is a span within the "pre" tag</span></pre>
<code>This is a code tag. <span>And this is a span within the "code" tag</span></code>
```

Note: `!important` is only necessary here because it's already used in your rule for `body, p, a, span`, otherwise ìnherit` would be sufficient.